# Is “tidbits” Bowdlerized or original?

Tags: american-english, offensive-language, word-usage

Our American English local paper insisted on changing a title from *ti**t**bits* to *ti**d**bits* for a column on minor local events and stories.

I, a British English speaker, have always pronounced and spelled this as *ti**t**bits*.

Are they accurate, or do they just want to avoid shocking their readership with any connection to bouncy lady-parts, in the same way that CNN insists on *IED* rather than *booby-trap*?

Comment: The predominant American pronunciation and spelling is "tidbit", and according to [Google Ngrams,](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=titbit%2Ctidbit&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) it has been this way for a long time. If the word was bowdlerized, this happened over 50 years ago ... your newspaper is not doing it now. I associate "titbit" with British English.

Comment: They just want to use what people expect to read. Nothing more than that.  To 99.9% of American readership, *titbit* would look like a sloppy typo.

Comment: @tchrist: Surely more than 0.1% of Americans would read enough *British* text to recognise that we normally write *titbits*. Would 99.9% of Americans think my *recognise* there was a typo?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I doubt it, actually and honestly. Also consider how rare the word *tidbit* is compared with *recognize*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am American and I dare say an almost obsessive lifelong reader fifty years old. I recognize recognise, but have never seen titbits.

Comment: It's also pertinent that "recognise" follows a well known BrE suffix pattern, whereas "titbit" is a one-off BrE difference. Many educated AmE speakers are aware of certain *common* differences with BrE but won't know less common differences. For example, I'm an AmE speaker and never heard of "titbit", but just off the top of my head I can think of many common AmE/BrEsuffix variations: "recogn-ize" vs "recogn-ise"; "lab-or" vs "lab-our"; "cent-er" vs "cent-re"; "pract-ice" vs "pract-ise". I'd wager many AmE people would immediately see "recognise" as a BrE spelling, but see "titbit" as a typo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Tid* dominates in the OED’s earliest citations illustrating the word's use, although the first citation for *tit* (1694) occurs only about 50 years after the first for *tid*. There is thus sufficient historical justification for either spelling. *Tit* in the mammary sense is a twentieth century latecomer.

Comment: +1, but I think consultation of *OED* s.v. *teat* and [*MED*] will convince you that "*tit* in the mammary sense" is no latecomer but in fact goes back to OE, and that in dialect (and perhaps spoken SE) it has survived supersession in written SE by an *e* spelling which represents a confusion with OF *tete* = "head", in the sense of "tip", for the nipple alone.

Comment: @StoneyB. _Tit_ as a variant spelling of _teat_ is one thing. _Tit_ as a word in its own right is another.

Comment: I would argue that the distinction is artificial: that *tit* 'in the mammary sense' and *teat* are not two words, but one, with variable pronunciation and spelling.

Comment: @StoneyB the two words are not cognates, according to Wiktionary. [tit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tit#Etymology_1) is from Old English titt, whereas [teat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teat#Etymology) is from French tette.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm According to [this source](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/tette), the French is of Germanic derivation, a cognate of OE *tit* and German *Zitze*. Doubtless the two coalesced in ME; observe the variety of [spellings](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=206952450&egdisplay=compact&egs=206966524). Certainly I was wrong to suggest that either is related to *tête* = "head", since that would still have been *teste*.